# I'm having trouble connecting Visual Studio 2019 to the Microsoft Hololens v2 Emulator for deployment

Tags: visual-studio, hololens, hololens-emulator

I am trying to deploy a simple unity app to the Hololens v2 emulator. I followed some tutorials to build the unity files according to the Hololens build framework. The tutorials on Microsoft show there being an option in visual studio 2019 to connect the debugger to the hololens v2 emulator application, but no such option exists on my installation of Visual Studio, despite it being within the stated requirements, version 19.2 or later. Mine is 19.11

[My version of Visual studio is 19.11, which should meet the requirement of 19.2 or later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HTKl.png)

here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2
It is shown having an option to target the emulator directly, and an option to target a remote device if using a physical hololens. I have neither option in my debug settings.
[What the tutorials show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxp8Q.png)

[What my visual studio shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG3BT.png)

[I attempted to set it up like the remote machine setup shown in the tutorial, getting the correct hololens machine name by accessing the ip address of the emulator, but to no avail, it refuses to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4eJt.png)

[It compiles properly, but then comes up with this error when run with those settings (with the correct machine name rather than a filler like I have in the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0zBp.png)

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to fix this? I have updated visual studio multiple times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure the correct project has been selected for the startup project. To change the startup project, you should navigate to **Solution Explorer**, right-click the desired project and choose **Set as StartUp Project** from the context-sensitive menu that is displayed.